# What Directshow filter event can I use to unblock the source stream thread upon filter shutdown?

Tags: delphi, filter, directshow, application-shutdown, dspack

I have a DirectShow filter written in Delphi 6 using the DSPACK component library.  It is a push source video filter.  The filter blocks on an event that is signaled in another thread that generates the video frames.  When a frame is ready, it is written into a shared memory area that the FillBuffer() method accesses when it is unblocked.  Is there a convenient DirectShow event that I can piggyback to unblock the FillBuffer() thread when the filter is being shutdown by DirectShow?  If not, what is "standard practice" in this area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard practice is [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and friends. You are waiting for one of the events that unlock your `FillBiffer`: availability of new video frame from external source, stop request arriving to your filter etc.

Comment: So should I use the usual DLL Thread/Process detach Windows events to unlock FillBuffer() before shutting down, or do I need to worry about unblocking FillBuffer() at all when the DLL is shutting down?  I thought there might be a dedicated DirectShow notification that filters get when a Filter is being unloaded but I guess not.

Comment: Filter graph would call filter's `Stop`, which would be forwarded to pin as pin's `Inactive`. You can override these methods in order to be able to set an event, which would be waited to in `FillBuffer` among other events, and this way you will be able to unlock on both new sample and request to stop.

Comment: Excellent.  I'll use those methods to clean things up in the event of the filter being shut down.